# Can't change from a static method but need to use method to set non-static property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got a method which is static and I can't make it non-static, however I need to set a non-static property using this method, however I can't due to it being static, suggestions?

```
//Update property with current availability
        private static void ReportAvailability()
        {
            if (NetworkStatus.IsAvailable)
            {
                Conn = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Conn = false;
            }
        }

        private bool _conn;
        public bool Conn
        {
            get { return _conn; }
            set
            {
                if (_conn != value)
                    _conn = value; RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you make the method non-static? Could you have a singleton object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smacks of a *serious* flaw somewhere in your architectural design and I would strongly recommend you fix it before it cascades into something far worse. To answer your question though, you could declare a static HashMap, which all instances register with, and then have your `ReportAvailability` function enumerate over all current instances:

```
public class MyClass : ViewModelBase, IDisposable
{
    static HashSet<MyClass> Instances = new HashSet<MyClass>();

    public MyClass()
    {
        Instances.Add(this);        // register
    }

    // dispose object to de-register 
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Instances.Remove(this);
    }

    private static void ReportAvailability()
    {
        foreach (var instance in Instances)
            instance.Conn = NetworkStatus.IsAvailable;
    }

    private bool _conn;
    public bool Conn
    {
        get { return _conn; }
        set
        {
            if (_conn != value)
                _conn = value; RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

Seriously though, you should fix the underlying problem. Start by having a look into dependency injection frameworks like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) etc which are specifically designed to help solve problems like this (e.g. by controlling scoping) without having to resort to such horrible hacks.

Answer (score 5):

Pass instance to the static method and set the property

```
//Update property with current availability
private static void ReportAvailability(SomeType someInstance)
{
    if (NetworkStatus.IsAvailable)
    {
       someInstance.Conn = true;
    }
    else
    {
        someInstance.Conn = false;
    }
}
```

In your case, somewhere in your non-static code use as:

```
ReportAvailability(this);
```

Comment: Change method body to: someInstance.Conn = NetworkStatus.IsAvailable;